Texture previews properly in material preview but not render preview
material preview and object shaderI have set up a texture as described here Tapering Textures with Nodes which works in material preview but which renders and bakes black. I have set up the render preview with lighting and the same hdri as the material preview but the issue persists. How can I fix this?

If you could include screenshots of your node setup, shaders, viewport, outliner, and anything else relevant to the issue, it would be a lot easier for people to help you.

Thanks I have added some screenshots now. Let me know if anything else would be useful.
